# Excluir valor do select comparando com outra tabela

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, phpmyadmin

Bom dia, estou desenvolvendo um site de agendamento, porém, estou com uma dificuldade enorme ao tentar exibir somente os horários que estão disponíveis.

Explicando: Existe a tabela `Agendamento´, onde fica registrado o horário de inicio`horainicia`e fim`horafim` do agendamento, exemplo tenho agendado para o dia 17 um horário de 10 da manhã até as 10:30 da manhã.

E existe a tabela `horariosdodia` que são os horário do dia que se inicia de 7 da manhã e em 10 e 10 minutos vai até as 18 da noite. Coluna chamada de ´horarios_livres`.

O meu grande problema é eliminar e mostra somente os horários disponíveis ao comparar `horainicio` com `horarios_livres` e excluir os horário tbm de 10:10, 10:20 já que está marcado de 10 as 10:30 os horarios de 10:10 e 10:20 não devem aparecer.

Eu tentei pelo `sql` mais meu conhecimento não foi o bastante para conseguir criar um `select` para realizar tal operação, tentei via `php` já direto na aplicação mas também não consegui, e ai preciso de uma ajuda de vocês.

Insert para a tabela horarios_livres:

```
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (070000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (071000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (072000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (073000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (074000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (075000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (080000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (081000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (082000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (083000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (084000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (085000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (090000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (091000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (092000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (093000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (094000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (095000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (100000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (101000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (102000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (103000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (104000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (105000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (110000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (111000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (112000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (113000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (114000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (115000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (120000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (121000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (122000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (123000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (124000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (125000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (130000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (131000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (132000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (133000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (134000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (135000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (140000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (141000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (142000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (143000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (144000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (145000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (150000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (151000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (152000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (153000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (154000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (155000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (160000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (161000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (162000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (163000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (164000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (165000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (170000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (180000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (181000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (182000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (183000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (184000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (185000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (190000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (191000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (192000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (193000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (194000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (195000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (200000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (201000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (202000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (203000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (204000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (205000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (210000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (211000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (212000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (213000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (214000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (215000);
INSERT INTO horariosdodia(horarios_livres) VALUES (220000);
```

Comment: Vc quer o que esta na tabela horarios livres e não esta no agendamento, isso?

Comment: Isso eu preciso que aparece oque ta no horarios_livres apareça e os horarios que estao no agendamento não apareça, so o valor final do agendamento na verdade deve aparecer pela lógica.

Comment: Tá, é sql server? Quais os tipos de dados das duas colunas?

Comment: ta em mysql, os tipo de dados sao time

Comment: Você tem pelo menos os inserts pra popular a tabela de horários livres? Se tiver edita a pergunta e posta por favor

Comment: Adicionei o insert

Comment: OK, vou montar o select e postar na resposta

Comment: ok, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realize uma verificação `NOT EXISTS` com relação a tabela `agendamento`, verificando se a coluna `horarios_livres` não está entre a `horainicia` e a `horafim` subtraindo 1 segundo.

```
SELECT d.*
  FROM horariosdodia d
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                    FROM agendamento a
                   WHERE d.horarios_livres BETWEEN a.horainicia AND SUBTIME(a.horafim, '0 0:0:1.00000'))
```

Comment: Muito bom, parabéns. Quem sabe sabe. Funcionou perfeitamente, era o que eu queria. Obrigado

Comment: Só me explica uma coisa, porque você subtraiu 1 segundo?

Comment: Porque senão o horário das 8h não apareceria caso você tivesse um agendamento das 7:30 as 8h. Na realidade eu acho que na agendamento é melhor se vc marcar sempre com 1 minuto a menos. Só tem que ver se não fica com um aspecto esquisito

Comment: Entendi, obrigado Sorack.